# Video File in Django Site how to watch films

Tags: python, django, filefield

[image]Hi everyone is trying to add to my project the ability to watch movies in the "FIlmy" application. And I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it only shows me a black window without loading.

My models:

```
          class Video(models.Model):
               name = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
               file = models.FileField(upload_to='films_image/', null=True, verbose_name="")
```

My views:

```
           @login_required
           def showvideo(request):
               firstvideo = Video.objects.last()
               videofile = firstvideo.videofile

               return render(request, "MyPage/MovieDetail.html", {'videofile': videofile})
```

My template:

```
           <h3><b>Clip</b></h3>


            <br>
            <video width='400' controls>
                   <source src='{{ videofile }}' type='video/mp4'>
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
```

I probably have a source error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

I've added to my URLS

```
                ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And my settings:

```
                 MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

                 MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
```

I added a file to my Movie foreign key and now I want the movie title to be viewed in my tempplate

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your source to

`<source src='{{ videofile.url }}' type='video/mp4'>`

Also change your views.py like

```
@login_required
def showvideo(request):
    firstvideo = Video.objects.last()
    videofile = firstvideo.file  # <-- As your model FileField name is 'file' and not videofile.

    return render(request, "MyPage/MovieDetail.html", {'videofile': videofile})
```

Comment: I added a photo

Answer (score 0):

Django's `FileField` has [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) attribute which you can use in template to get url of file:

```
<source src='{{ videofile.url }}' type='video/mp4'>
```

Also you should change settings to this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your code `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` mixed up.

Comment: Dont' work :(
Maybe add: <source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ videofile.url }}' type='video/mp4'>

Comment: @kuba check updated answer. Looks like you have incorrect settings.

Comment: @kuba and another comment. What is model's field name? Is it `file` or `videofile`? Shouldn't it be `videofile = firstvideo.file` in your view?

Comment: My models Video is "file" but 
My views named "videofile".

Comment: I mean if you have in model this code `file = models.FileField` than you should use in view `file` attribute instead of `videofile`: videofile = firstvideo.file

Comment: It still doesn't work, I think the problem is with my source, as if it did not see the added.mp4 file

Comment: Did you swap `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` as in my answer?

Comment: Yes:
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')